# Ingresar un caracter en un String en la posicion i

Tags: java, string

Hola tengo un proyecto pero estoy atorado en un par de lineas. Me interesa, como el titulo lo dice ingresar un carácter en una posición de alguna cadena nueva.

El programa lo que hace es que va imprimiendo caracteres pero estos los quiero que se guarden en una cadena 1 a 1 en la posición 0, 1, 2,... hasta el termino del for que estoy utilizando.

```
for(int i=0; i<data.length(); i++){  
      int Ascii=Dia;
      Ascii= Ascii + data.charAt(i);
      for(int k=8, Pot ; k>=0; k--){
            Pot=(int) Math.pow(2, k);
            if(Ascii>=Pot){
                System.out.print("1");
                Ascii=Ascii-Pot;
            }else{
                System.out.print("0")
            }              
       }
}
```

En el codigo que les comparto quisiera modificar el system.out que esta dentro del if y modificarlo para guardarlo en una cadena uno a uno.
En otra parte del programa ocupo hacer lo mismo pero en esta ocasión es un char en vez de un numero

Comment: Hola Alejo, para mejorar el formato de tu pregunta y así aumentar las posibilidades de poder ayudarte, te recomiendo que revises la página de ayuda sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Puedes comenzar por compartir el código que tengas hecho, como para tener un punto de partida. Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static String addChar(String cadena, int posicion, String letra) {
        
        String[] array = new String[cadena.length() + 1];
        String[] cadenaArray = cadena.split("");
        String res = "La posición se encuentra fuera de la longitud de la cadena";
        if(posicion < cadena.length()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
            String letraCadena = cadenaArray[i];
            if(i == posicion) {
                array[i] = letra;
                array[i+1] = letraCadena;
                i+=1;
            } else {
                array[i] = letraCadena;
            }
            
            res = String.join("", array);
            }
        }
        
        return res;
    }
```

Este método te añade a la posición que tú le digas, el caracter que tú le digas.

He puesto letra en el método pero puede ser un String lo que añadas, por lo que si al String "Hola" le añades "Mundo" con ese método, te añadirá "HolaMundo", por ejemplo, si le dices que la posición es la última de la cadena. Si la posición se encuentra fuera del tamaño de la cadena, devuelve un mensaje de error.

Answer (score 0):

Pruba con este método

```
private String intoString(String textoReal, String textoInsert, int pos){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder= new StringBuilder(textoReal);
        stringBuilder.insert(pos,textoInsert);
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Donde textoReal es tu texto ....textoInsert es el texto que vas a insertar y pos es la posición donde vas a introducir textoInsert dentro de textoReal.. Saludos y espero que te ayude en algo